# What does a red-colored filename mean?

Tags: ls, colors

I have been exploring files in bash, and in /etc/ssl/certs, most of the filenames are light blue. There is a red filename though, and I can't figure out why it is red.

Most of the files in this directory are .pem files. The red one is also a .pem file. It happens to be something like `China_Internet_Network_Information_Center...pem`

According to [this stack exchange question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls) , light blue filenames mean linked files, while red file names mean "archived" files. What does that mean? Looking at the directory with `ls -all`, I still can't tell what makes the filename red. Can anyone explain why it is red?

Comment: sounds like ls is coloring the files based on certain criteria; it might be helpful to include the `ls -al` output. My suspicion is a broken symlink.

Comment: also, the result of `echo $LS_COLORS`

Comment: By the way, there is no such `ls` option as `-all`.  There is a `-a` (all) option and a `-l` (long) option.  When you say `ls -all`, you are specifying the `-a` option once and the `-l` option twice (which does no good). You might as well just say `ls -al`. (Or `ls -la`, or `ls -a -l` or `ls -l -a`, all of which are equivalent.)

Comment: My guess would be a broken link, as the file is in a directory with other links. `ls -lah` the file to confirm.

Comment: you can edit `/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh` and change `auto` to `none` at the bottom of the file where it does the alias of `ls`.  I never liked any of that color highlighting.  `alias l='ls -FC'` *ftw!*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First you need to know the VT100 color code

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

I don't know what your text actually looks like, but "red text" is 31.

Then you want to look at the `dircolors` command, and find everything that has a 31 in it.  In my case, that would be:

```
or=40;31;01
*.tar=01;31
*.tgz=01;31
*.arj=01;31
*.taz=01;31
*.lzh=01;31
*.lzma=01;31
*.tlz=01;31
*.txz=01;31
*.zip=01;31
*.z=01;31
*.Z=01;31
*.dz=01;31
*.gz=01;31
*.lz=01;31
*.xz=01;31
*.bz2=01;31
*.bz=01;31
*.tbz=01;31
*.tbz2=01;31
*.tz=01;31
*.deb=01;31
*.rpm=01;31
*.jar=01;31
*.rar=01;31
*.ace=01;31
*.zoo=01;31
*.cpio=01;31
*.7z=01;31
*.rz=01;31
```

Then you can go here

http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors

which tells you

- `or` is an "orphan", a symbolic link with no target
- the rest are file globs that match assorted archive and compression schemes

`.pem` doesn't appear on my list, and `.pem` files aren't colored on my system, so I can't help you further than that.  But I'd guess "orphan".

Comment: It turned out to be an orphan. Another question: How did you output `dircolors` line by line like that?

Comment: @jabe -- i did it by hand, looking for colons and replacing them with returns.

Comment: @jabe -- i can't edit my older comment, so `dircolors | sed -e 's/:/\n/g'`

Answer (score 12):

Most Linux distros by default usually color-code files so you can immediately recognize what type they are. You are right that red means archive file and `.pem` is an archive file. **An archive file is just a file composed of other files.** Examples you might be more familiar with might include `.zip`, `.rar`, or `.tar` files.

If you want to know more about .pem files this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) has a good explanation

Comment: Linux is the kernel, and has no concept of color codes for file names. You are talking about the default bash (or another shell) configuration included in the distribution.

Comment: @phihag: It's probably not whatever shell you're using, but (as mentioned above) specific to the ls command.  You can use the option --color=never to turn colorization off (my choice), or the dircolors command to set it to whatever you prefer.

Comment: Archive? Only context I know of `pem` is with cryptographic keys. Is it even allowed to contain arbitrary data?

Comment: @jpmc26 it contains multiple certificates in one .pem so it is considered an archive file.

Comment: The weird thing is, is that the vast majority of the .pem files there are light blue. I suspect it is a broken link.