# Why are Linux namespace links in /proc red in color?

Tags: symlink, proc, namespace

I inspected the symlinks in an Ubuntu VM for the namespace related directories under `/proc/PID/ns`. I see all the links are in red color.

[image]

I even tried to test using `unshare` to see if I can create a new namespace. I tested using mount namespace and a new namespace is assigned to the new process.

```
root@VM:/# ll /proc/$$/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ** mnt -> mnt:[4026531840] **
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 net -> net:[4026531957]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
root@VM:/# 
root@VM:/# unshare --mount
root@VM:/# 
root@VM:/# ll /proc/$$/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 ** mnt -> mnt:[4026532226] **
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 net -> net:[4026531957]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 21 01:56 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

Can anyone tell why the symlinks are in red ? Does this mean the namespace feature is not working ?

Comment: duplicated of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345797/72456 + duplicated of https://askubuntu.com/q/17299/283843 on AU + duplicated of https://superuser.com/q/543397/370509 on SU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `ls`’ representation of broken symlinks; see [What does a red-colored filename mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345797/86440)

The fact that the links are red, or even that the symlinks are broken, doesn’t imply anything with regard to whether namespaces are working or not; it’s only related to the namespace representation in `/proc`. The existence of the files means that the corresponding namespaces are set up, and presumably working correctly.